# rsyslog not emitting any log

Tags: debian, sftp

I try to log chroot users sftp accesses and operations on debian 2.5 following this tutorial http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/sftp-logging-chroot/

I cant make it work so far

/etc/rsyslog.d/sftp.conf

```
module(load="imuxsock")
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/var/ftp/userA/dev/log" CreatePath="on")
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/var/ftp/userB/dev/log" CreatePath="on")

if $programname == 'internal-sftp' then /var/log/sftp.log
& stop
```

sockets (same for userB):

```
ls /var/ftp/userA/dev/ -lha
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 31 16:08 .
drw-r-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K May 31 12:00 ..
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 May 31 16:08 log
```

I put the log file in 777 to be sure it's not a permissions problem

```
ls /var/log/sftp.log  -lha
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 31 14:50 /var/log/sftp.log
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -l INFO -f AUTH
Match Group ftpusers
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
```

then

```
$sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
[ ok ] Restarting ssh (via systemctl): ssh.service.
$sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
[ ok ] Restarting rsyslog (via systemctl): rsyslog.service.
```

I can't find anything usefull in /var/log/messages nor /var/log/syslog

please help !!

thank

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly wrong and it will never be true:

```
if $programname == 'internal-sftp' then /var/log/sftp.log
```

The `internal-sftp` is just a placeholder in `sshd_config`. The actual program that runs the sftp server is still `sshd`.

If you want to distinguish `sftp` logs, you will need to do that using syslog facility (`-f` switch to `internal-sftp`), but I am not sure if this setup is supported in Debian (the process is in chroot so you do not have access to the logging socket in `/dev/log`).

Comment: that's the whole idea , create a socket so that chroot users could write to, and by some rsyslog magic it would write it to the /var/log/syslog, there are many tutorials saying it can be done that way(or using legacy rsyslog instructions)

Comment: I use -f, please consider reading my setup again...Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -l INFO -f AUTH

Comment: But `ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002` ... which one of them is effective? There were several bugs preventing this logging from working. Make sure you have up-to-date OpenSSH.

Comment: ...upgrading openssh-sftp-server did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Note: There is a [Bug **1761630**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1761630) as of 2019 for Ubuntu 18.04 that doesnt allow rsyslog to create custom logs. Instead all the logging goes to `/var/log/syslog`

So The steps i took to resolve it are:

1. Set up SFTP over SSHD correctly.
2. Set up the Chroot Directories your require e.g. `/home/sftp/$DIR_CHROOT...`
3. Creage groups for the chroot user eg. `groupadd sftpgroup`
   In SSHD COnfig make sure to use Facility LOCAL7 and log level INFO

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f LOCAL7 -l INFO
Match group sftpgroup
    ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/$DIR_CHROOT...
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -f LOCAL7 -l INFO
```

4. Very important Creat a socket for the Chroot Jail user log `sudo mkdir -p /home/sftp/$DIR_CHROOT/dev`
5. Give permissions `sudo chmod 755 /home/sftp/$DIR_CHROOT/dev`
6. Create a dummy file `sudo touch /home/sftp/$DIR_CHROOT/dev/log`
7. Configure Rsyslog> create a custom file for handling the SFTP log socket created in step above
8. Add a Unix Listening Socket

```
# Create socket within chrooted directories to allow for logging. You could try commented options below but in ubuntu 18.04 they are useless and everything goes to `syslog`

$AddUnixListenSocket /home/sftp/$DIR_CHROOT/dev/log

# Other Folder
#$AddUnixListenSocket /home/sftp/other

# Parse the data logged at level INFO and facility LOCAL7 into /var/log/sftp.log
# LOCAL7.info /var/log/sftp.log

# Report logins and logoffs
# :syslogtag,startswith,"sftp-server" /var/log/sftp.log
```

9. Restart Services

```
sudo service ssh restart && sudo service rsyslog restart
```

10. Create the ChRooted users if they dont exist already

**Debug**

```
sudo service ssh status && sudo service rsyslog status
# you should see the file Operations
sudo less /var/log/syslog
sudo less /var/log/sftp.log
```

---